# ui-define used in composite component doesn't work on primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

Now I have to build a composite component to implement a specific function.
Our layout page is like the following:

layout.xhtml

```xml
<p:layout >
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border:0px;">
        <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
<ui:insert name="dialogContent"></ui:insert>
```

content.xhtml

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns:hs="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" template="/layout/layout.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="content">
                 <p:layout>
            <h:form id="bodyForm" style="margin:0px">
                <p:layoutUnit position="west">
                    <p:panel>
                        <hs:dlg></hs:dlg>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                                ...
            </h:form>
        </p:layout>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

dlg.xhtml(composite component)

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
        <composite:interface>
            ...
        </composite:interface>
        <composite:implementation>
                <p:inputText id="inputId" onclick="dlgVar.show();" />
            <ui:define name="dialogContent">
                <h:form id="dlgForm" prependId="">
                    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlgVar">
                    ...
                    </p:dialog>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </composite:implementation>
 </ui:composition>
```

I hope when I click the input, dialog will be open. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've tried adding `appendToBody="true"` on the dialog and removing `<ui:define name="dialogContent">`, dialog can be open, but there's no independent `dlgForm` in the page, which will cause some problems when I submit form data.

So how can I render dialog in the right place in layout.xhtml?